Got notifed of a response to a comment but now I cannot see my comment or the response and there is no history
I recently added a comment regarding this issue How to reject merge request in GitLab? which asked a follow up question looking for clarification on if the feature in question was enabled by default.
I got notified of another comment responding to my user name but when I click on the notification neither my original comment or the response can be seen which left me really confused. There does not appear to be any history of either comment.
The notification was for Apr 23 (this year) and my comment was made in the last month or two yet the issues history stops at Nov 15 2023.
Is this some caching issue or is it possible the comments have been deleted without any history?

Comments never show up in history. Only mods can see deleted comments.

It looks like your comment and the reply to it were on an answer that is now deleted (Users with 10k+ rep can see deleted posts, not deleted comments though, in this case the comments weren't deleted).

Does this answer your question? What happened to the comments? They all disappeared

Odd, in the history I can see items labeled as 'comment'. I guess this does answer my question though it seems odd that the deleted 'Answer' does not appear in the history either. I guess I don't have permission to see that either?

I'm guessing that the answer was deleted after the notification was issued.

@karmasponge You need 10k+ to see deleted answers whether directly or on the timeline. If you could see the timeline of the deleted answer you'd see the comment there.

The answer is deleted (at Apr 25 at 0:00) for moderation reasons and as you don't have 10K yet, you can't see the answer nor the comment on it.
Shameless plug: I have a userscript that more clearly tells you if a comment or answer link you follow has been deleted: Show a warning message when you follow a link to a deleted answer or comment
The still visible comment (posted at Apr 23 at 7:28, 8 minutes after yours) on the deleted answer says:

Not sure, beside what the documentation says. Maybe you need to activate a feature flag.

I'm not sure if and how this information is best preserved. Maybe you can search for questions on Gitlab feature flags and if none exists that answer your specific question, consider asking a new question about how to enable the feature and then self-answer. I do note that for some reason self-answers aren't always appreciated, so as a mitigation strategy give it 6 to 8 days before you self-answer.

It's a shame that by default it leaves users in the dark. Would be nice if the notifications upon redirection notified you that the related content no longer exists.

UX attention is on money making and other useless features like Discussions. The public platform product management isn't interested in harvesting low-hanging fruit.

@karmasponge normally the notification is supposed to get deleted but it doesn't happen sometimes, it's a long known bug.

The answer post these comments were on was deleted. That's why you can't see the comments (or the answer post they were posted on).
This particular deletion may need correction (debatable. the post also has other issues). I've notified a mod about it. The answers were blanket deleted and false-positives are being handled manually (mod statement).

No but we're in a bit of a gnarly time period where it being deleted because it was algorithmically-generated (sorry, I refuse to call it "AI") is pretty much the default bet. It is hard to question deletions now.
